# How do I deduce the SD from regression and ANOVA tables?

Tags: estimation, self-study

[image]

This is a Minitab printout. I want to find the value of A5, or S.

I think S is supposed to be the sample standard deviation, but I don't know how to calculate it. Any tips on how I should go about calculating it?

Comment: Is this for a homework or a test?  "A5", "A6", and "A7" look like they are placeholders for values that were produced but are being hidden from you on purpose.

Comment: It's a homework problem. I can do A6 and A7 by myself, I just need some tips on A5.

Comment: Consider the relationships between SD, variance, and total sum of squares about the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! It's the sqrt of residual SS / (n-2). Cheers!

Comment: In that case it's not the "sample standard deviation," but the residual standard deviation. :-)